# Factory test - How to cast in TypeScript

Tags: test, factory

I am new to solidity and am now facing a problem.
I created a factory :

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;


import "./Offering.sol";

contract OfferFactory {
    Offering[] _offers;
    function createOffer(string memory  _OffreName ,  address  _SPcollection, uint256  _SPId, uint256  _OfferingPeriodInDays, uint256  _TokenizationPeriodInDays,uint256  _OfferSize,
       uint256 _TokenLifeTimeDay, uint256  _minimumBidSize, uint256  _maximumBidSize,address  _depositFeeAddress, address _TokenAddress
    ) public returns(address) {

        Offering _of =new Offering(
                _OffreName,
                _SPcollection,
                _SPId,
                _OfferingPeriodInDays,
                _TokenizationPeriodInDays,
                _TokenLifeTimeDay,
                _OfferSize,
                _minimumBidSize,
                _maximumBidSize,
                _depositFeeAddress,
                _TokenAddress);
        _offers.push(_of);
                
        return address(_of);

    }
}
```

that creates offers.

when I try to test in hardhat I do :

```
    let of1  =await offerfactory.createOffer("offer3Name" , _SPCollection_address, 1, 10, 10,1000000,365, 1,1000000,ETH_ACCOUNT_ADMIN_1,  _StableColb_address);
```

From there I am unable to have _of1 recognized as an Offering..
So any attempt to call one of its function fails.

Do you know how I should do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a contract factory inside **Solidity** but you need a contract factory in **Hardhat (Javascript)** so you can deploy and use your contract factory. It would look like:

```js
import '@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox'; // you need this to use ethers from hardhat
import { ethers } from 'hardhat';



const offerFactoryContractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('OfferFactory');
const offerFactoryContract = await offerFactoryContract.deploy();

const offer1Contract = offerFactoryContract.createOffer( ... );
```